# compile c++ in powershell

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

I have been trying to find out a way to setup my **PowerShell** so that I could compile my **C++** codes written in **Sublime Text 3**. I have looked over the internet but couldn't find any solution. Which compiler should I use and how do I run the compiler in PowerShell? Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Powershell can compile and include **C#** code, not C++, so you'll still have to refer to your C++ compiler to compile C++.

Comment: @Vesper: Sorry, but I was unaware of that Powershell can compile C#. Do you have a ref?

Comment: But can't I run any C++ compiler in PowerShell and compile my codes using that compiler?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Sublime Text, really.

Comment: Ya, it has nothing to do with Sublime Text but I just mentioned it because I was using it.

Comment: @Vesper e.g. for setting up PowerShell for Python I followed following steps and it worked. Step1: I downloaded python 2.7 and installed it on my machine Step2: I set up the environment variable as [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx) it's explained how to include a C# code. I meant this. If you're speaking about pure compilation, say to make a DLL, you'll still have to use `csc.exe`.